# Memory leaks when embed YouTube videos in Metro App using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, microsoft-metro

I want to play some YouTube video in my Metro app. I embed YouTube video in my app using YouTube Iframe API([Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)). Then I meet a serious problem of memory leak. If I embed a YouTube video and then remove it, the memory will increase about 5MB and nerver decrease any more. Demo code is here:
default.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>iframeTest</title>
<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
<!-- iframeTest references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body style ="">
<button id="remove" style="display:block; float:left;">remove a video</button>
<button id="add" style="display:block; float:left;">add a video</button>
</body>
</html>
```

default.js fragment:

```
document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var ifrs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    if (ifrs.length > 0) {
            document.body.removeChild(ifrs[ifrs.length - 1]);
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var testYoutubeDiv = document.createElement('div');
        testYoutubeDiv.style.cssFloat = 'left';
        testYoutubeDiv.style.width = '400px';
        testYoutubeDiv.style.height = '300px';
        MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {
            testYoutubeDiv.innerHTML = "<iframe id='player' type='text/html' width='400' height='300' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com' frameborder='0'></iframe>";

        });
        document.body.appendChild(testYoutubeDiv);
    });
```

Then, I write a similar .html file and test it in IE10.0 and Chrome. I find IE10.0 also has memory leak problem but chrome has not. And the memory leak problem in IE10.0 is less serious than in Metro App.
test html code was here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>iframeTest</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function load() {
    document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var ifrs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
        if (ifrs.length > 0) {
            document.body.removeChild(ifrs[ifrs.length - 1]);
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var testYoutubeDiv = document.createElement('div');
        testYoutubeDiv.style.cssFloat = 'left';
        testYoutubeDiv.style.width = '400px';
        testYoutubeDiv.style.height = '300px';
        testYoutubeDiv.innerHTML = "<iframe id='player' type='text/html' width='400' height='300' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com' frameborder='0'></iframe>"; 
        document.body.appendChild(testYoutubeDiv);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload ="load()">
<button id="remove" style="display:block; float:right;">remove a video</button>
<button id="add" style="display:block; float:right;">add a video</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I notice that IE(and maybe Metro App) does not use WebKit Engine to deal with javascript code. Is there any way to reduce memory leak in Metro App?

Comment: The memory isn't intended/guaranteed to be released immediately (or ever). From what you've demonstrated we cannot say if it's a leak or not. Would it grow to 1GB if you add and remove it 200 times?

Comment: As you say, I test the code in Metro App. I add about 100 YouTube videos and then remove them when they loaded completely, the memory increases about 600MB. Then I have lunch, take a walk. When I am back, the memory remains about 550MB. Can we regard this as memory leak?

Comment: not actually. It might wait for a moment when it's really necessary to collect the garbage

Answer (score 1):

Create an iframe in html file

```
<iframe id="ifr_video"></iframe>
```

And then add a source to that iframe using javascript, while adding source find the id of YouTube URL by spliting, for example if the YouTube URL is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnehCBoYLbc, the ID is ZnehCBoYLbc, then define the source like the following for finding ID and adding source

```
var Url_splits = Youtube_Video_url.split("/");
var Url_length = Url_splits.length;
var Ytube_id = Url_splits[(Url_length - 1)];
document.getElementById("ifr_video").src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Ytube_id;
```

In HTML

```
        <video id="VideoSource" style="border:1px solid black;"  controls="controls" ></video>
        <iframe class="youtube-player" id="ifr_video" type="text/html" width=100% height=100% allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In JS (inside ready function)

```
id("VideoSource").msPlayToSource.connection.addEventListener("statechanged", playToSrcStateChangeHandler);

        function playToSrcStateChangeHandler(eventIn) {
                var states = Windows.Media.PlayTo.PlayToConnectionState;
                if (eventIn.currentState === states.disconnected) {
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("PlayTo connection state: Disconnected", "sample", "status");
                } else if (eventIn.currentState === states.connected) {
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("PlayTo connection state: Connected", "sample", "status");
                } else if (eventIn.currentState === states.rendering) {
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("PlayTo connection state: Rendering", "sample", "status");
                }
            }

        Video_Path = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + new_id;

        //new_id is the Youtube video id For example,..
        in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnehCBoYLbc ,  id is ZnehCBoYLbc            

        function playYouTubeVideo(Video_Path) {
                document.getElementById("ifr_video").src = Video_Path;
                id("VideoSource").style.display='none';
            }

        function playWebContent(Video_Path) {
                document.getElementById("ifr_video").style.display = 'none';
                var localVideo = id("VideoSource");
                var videoStabilization = Windows.Media.VideoEffects.videoStabilization;

                localVideo.src = Video_Path;
                localVideo.play();
            }
```

Reference: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-PlayTo-Sample-fedcb0f9